# select all textarea content and let the user copy it under iOS and Android: some issues

Tags: android, ios, select, copy, textarea

I am trying to create a JavaScript code that selects all text from a textarea when the user focus it (using onfocus event).

The textarea contains a very long text which is a URL and uses just one row (one line of text). Wrap text is not allowed with "word-wrap" set to "normal", "text-wrap" set to "none" and    "white-space" set "nowrap". And "overflow-x" property is set to "auto" (I also tried to set it to "scroll"). I don't want to use an external service to compress the URL and compressing the URL parameters with compression algorithms is not enough to make it little enough.

All works fine with desktop browsers: the user focus the textarea and all text is selected (they just need to copy it with a keyboard shortcut or the mouse). But on mobile devices (Android and iOS) there are some issues:

Under Android's default browser, when you focus the textarea (although it has readOnly attribute set to true), it shows the on-screen keyboard. No toolbar with "copy" option is shown. But you can hold the finger on the textarea again (which makes you lose all selection), then the "copy" toolbar option appears and you can choose "Select All" and then "Copy".

Under iOS 8.1.1 (using Safari), it is even worse. The text gets selected but the toolbar which has the option for "copy" (to Clipboard) hides as soon as "input" or "setSelectionRange" method are called (it doesn't matter whether I call those functions with a setTimeout or not). When you hold the finger on the screen (losing all selection), you can choose which part of the text you want to select but you can't select the text that overflows the textarea. The system doesn't provide an option to select all text as on Android.

Attaching the function that selects all text to another event which is not onfocus (onclick, onmousedown, onmouseup, ontouchstart, ountouchend...) doesn't work since makes the toolbar with "copy" option hide as soon as it is called. I also tried to use setTimeout and even setInterval with all those events listed without success. Returning false or preventDefault doesn't do anything at all. I also tried to use "selectionStart" and "selectionEnd" instead of "select" or "setSelectionRange" methods.

So what I need is either a way to avoid the "copy" toolbar being hidden or otherwise a way to let the user select all text area (and copy it, of course).

Thank you in advance.

Cheers,
 Joan